# The term 'pip' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet on windows 10 despite successful installation

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

Here I check the installed version of pip
`py -m pip --version`

```
pip 21.0.1 from C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

Now I try to run a pip command

`pip install pip --target $HOME\\.pyenv`

```
pip: The term 'pip' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Try `python -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the scripts folder  to PATH

`C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`

or

`C:\Python39\Scripts`
(depending on how you have installed python locate and add python/scripts folder)

Answer (score 1):

Just use on the terminal:

```
py -m pip install
```

followed by the library you want to install. It tends to work.